# Jenkins push failed for dockers

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to do a push into my docker repo.

my github repo is here for reference with my jenkins file https://github.com/leeadh/braintree_example.git

However, it keeps showing this error where it a passphrase for my new root key is not created. Why is this so?

PS: to give some context my DOCKER_CONTENT_TRSUT in cmd is 0. Hence, I am unsure what is casuing this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a missing credentials error.

You need to set credentials to connect to your github and docker registry.

Here you can see detailed instructions for setting them up:

- Github: https://gist.github.com/misterbrownlee/3708738
- Docker (see Docker Host Certificate Authentication): https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Comment: Hi Nicola I don't think it's that as  the code can gitpull. This happens when it's trying to do a docker  push